# Better way to do this If statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, refactoring

Pretty simple: I wrothe the following `if/else` statement:

```
   if (cr1.ins <= cr2.ins) {
     console.log("[ROUND 1] Creature 1 (#" + cr1.num + ") is attacking first.");
    cr2.hlt = cr2.hlt - (cr1.atk + cr2.ins);
    console.log("[HIT] Creature #" + cr2.num + " health reduced to " + cr2.hlt);
    if (cr2.hlt <= 0) {
      console.log("[DEATH] Creature #" + cr2.num + " Eliminated");
      remove(cr2);
    } else {
      console.log("[ROUND 2] Creature 2 (#" + cr2.num + ") is attacking second.");
      cr1.hlt = cr1.hlt - (cr2.atk + cr1.ins);
      console.log("[HIT] Creature #" + cr1.num + " health reduced to " + cr1.hlt);
      if (cr1.hlt <= 0) {
      console.log("[DEATH] Creature #" + cr1.num + " Eliminated");
      remove(cr1);
    }
    }
   } else {
    cr1.hlt = cr1.hlt - (cr2.atk + cr1.ins);
    console.log("[ROUND 1] Creature 2 (#" + cr2.num + ") is going first.");
    console.log("[HIT] Creature #" + cr1.num + " health reduced to " + cr1.hlt);
    if (cr1.hlt <= 0) {
      console.log("[DEATH] Creature #" + cr1.num + " Eliminated");
      remove(cr1);
    } else {
      console.log("[ROUND 2] Creature 1 (#" + cr1.num + ") is going second.");
      cr2.hlt = cr2.hlt - (cr1.atk + cr2.ins);
      console.log("[HIT] Creature #" + cr2.num + " health reduced to " + cr2.hlt);
      if (cr2.hlt <= 0) {
      console.log("[DEATH] Creature #" + cr2.num + " Eliminated");
      remove(cr2);
    }
    }
   }
```

I know there's probably a better way to do this, as the code in `else{ }` is basically the same as `if{ }` with some variable name changes, so, any suggestions for changes or refactoring? I'd like to improve readability and speed while accomplishing the same task as it performs currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can simplify this, the general approach would be

```
if (cr1.ins > cr2.ins) {
  [cr2, cr1] = [cr1, cr2]; // just swap them!
}
attack(cr1, cr2);
if (cr2.hlt > 0) {
  attack(cr2, cr1);
}
```

For your logging statements with `Creature 1/2` you would also need to pass through that information, so it might become something like

```
const a = {designator: "Creature 1", creature: cr1},
      b = {designator: "Creature 2", creature: cr2};
const [first, second] = cr1.ins <= cr2.ins ? [a, b] : [b, a];
attack({attacker: first, defender: second, round: 1});
if (second.creature.hlt > 0)
  attack({attacker: second, defender: first, round: 2});
```

Of course, if you refactor this to use an `attack` function as above, it might become shorter to write out the `if`/`else` again.